# 2003 Chevrolet Truck Suburban 2500 4WD 6.0L FI OHV Volt Drop test on fuel pump

Tags: voltage

I performed a voltage drop test on my 2003 Suburban fuel pump and the negative side of the fuel pump returned a voltage drop of only .02 Volts using the 20 Volt setting my multimeter. That's only 20 millivolts. Is that even possible to drop so little voltage and for my fuel pump to be that efficient?

I cleaned several ground contacts after I dropped the tank and replaced the fuel pump already and the new fuel pump didn't work. That led me to learning about volt drop testing. At first I rear probed the connector on top of the fuel pump and came back with .06 on the positive side and 0.00 on the ground side. I eventually pulled out my rear probe and put it in again and the ground came back .02 after several tests which is only 20 millivolts...well under the .3 volts max droppage allowed.

I was just glad to get a reading on the negative side greater than 0.00.  I'm hoping that I have now confirmed that either my new pump is bad OR that the ground contacts I cleaned were bad contacts and now are good clean ground contacts.

Looking forward for some feedback. I LOVE This shit for the record fixing my own stuff!!! I'm a 100% Independent Life insurance broker by day and a closet mechanic at night. Thanks in advance for any and all feedback!

Comment: `.06 on the positive side and 0.00 on the ground side` .. that indicates that the pump is unpowered ... try measuring the voltage drops when there is actually some voltage to be dropped

Comment: Seems like this belongs on [Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Im not familiar with the specific vehicle  BUT:  I'd exppect 12V +ve to be fed to the pump - either continuous or pulsed. Testing from a good known ground point (chassis filed to bare metal or similar) I'd expect 12V to be seen from the pump supply to this ground. || The drop from pump negative to ground tests your pump ground  quality but is only useful when the feed is correct. | Only when you see 12V sometimes or always from feed wire to ground WITH the pump installed can you then usefully test the ground connection drop.

Comment: I did check for the 12 V from the battery to the pump. Before I turn the key to the on position it shows 12 V at the pump. Once I turned the key to the on position it drops from 12v to 0.06 V on the positive side.

Comment: @NunyabIzzness The voltage AT the pump should not drop like that. It seems very likely that a contact before the pump is bad. It COULD be a fuse with enough leakage for a meter to see 12V - maybe through a monitoring circuit or bulb. A 12V lamp connected from +ve lead to ground should  illuminate. (A smart circuit may detect the pump absence and stop this BUT that is unlikely).